# How should I load a csv file by c++ for being able to query the table like in Pandas?

Tags: python, c++, csv, pandas

In Pandas it is perfectly easy to load a csv file and query its rows by column values. For instance;

```
X2 = X[(X.col1 == 4) & (X.col2 == 5)]
```

Now in c++ I would like to have such functionality. I need to read a csv file and then retrieve rows by the column values for nested iterations;

```
DATA is defined as a csv table
for each unique DATA.col1 value VAL :
  ROWS = (DATA.col1 == VAL) // get rows where col1 value is VAL
  for each unique ROWS.col2 value VAL2:
     ROWS2 = (ROWS.col2 == VAL2)
     Do something with ROWS2
```

I guess this means multiple level of indexing. What is your suggestion to implement such a functionality in C++.

In my naive implementation, I try to use hash map for each combination of col1 and col2 values but it makes the indexing problem really big.

Comment: why a hash map and not a vector of vectors? Is the file particularly big?

Comment: also, you can use [google's csv parser](https://code.google.com/p/csv-parser-cplusplus/).

Comment: @ArnonZilca file has 4200000 lines

Comment: @ArnonZilca I guess compiling Google's Parser on Windows is another problem .

Comment: It's only 2 source files (1 cpp, 1 hpp), and looks like it should easily compile on windows (according to the includes inside). there's a zip pack with the sources.